# C# - Changing variable when publishing

Tags: c#

I am trying to change a "testing" variable to TRUE when I publish my app. I keep forgetting to change it back to false when publishing and go into a panic when things start to go wrong. The reason I have a "testing" variable is to execute different mysql commands to a testing database rather than production.

I have tried

```
#if DEBUG
```

but that did not work as it is still in DEBUG when I publish. I would like something where I dont have to remember to change something to a different value manually (DEBUG/RELEASE)... unless I am missing something

EDIT:

I am publishing a WinForms app in Visual Studio 2019. All I do is go to build tab and hit publish.
Would changing it to release mode allow me to change a variable value?

Comment: We have no context here - what kind of app you have, what "publishing" consists of, etc. There are various different approaches you might want to use, but they really depend on context.

Comment: `but that did not work as it is still in DEBUG when I publish. `  --- you push debug builds to production?  That seems like a problem.  Also, please read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - then edit your question to add context

Comment: Why don't you publish your app as release version?

Comment: Use environment variable that defaults to release value. While debugging, set the env variable to debug value.

Comment: "still in DEBUG when I publish" figure that out first...

Comment: Seems I have been doing this wrong for a while. I will start changing to Release and that would fix the #if DEBUG not working. Unless there is a better way?

Comment: @RobinYoHood always publish applications in release as the compiler is going to be optimizing a lot of the solution. Namely a lot of debugging symbols and info will be scrubbed from the release build. You don't want to ever be deploying something that is both larger and slower than it needs to be, even if the impact is marginal.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in my Code with:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        #if DEBUG
            System.Console.WriteLine("DebugMode = ON");
        #else
            // release stuff goes here
        #endif
    }
```

and it works fine :)

I think you forgot the #endif and you must publish your Project as ReleaseBuild not as DebugBuild

Hope i could help!